# Agenda con Tkinter no guarda los contactos

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy haciendo una especie de agenda de contactos la cual muestra el nombre, el número de teléfono y el correo de cada uno de ellos. La cosa es que el programa no carga los contactos, cuando uso el botón de cargar contactos no hace nada.

Me gustaría que me aclararan la situación, si me falta algo o cuál es el problema.

Cualquier duda acerca del código me dicen, gracias de antemano.

```
import pickle
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from time import sleep

SAVE_FILE_NAME = "contacts.save"


def add_contact(contacts, name, phone, email):
    contact = {
        "name": name,
        "phone": phone,
        "email": email
    }
    contacts.append(contact)
    return contact


def add_contact_tk(contacts, name, phone, email, frame_contact_list):
    contact = add_contact(contacts, name, phone, email)
    cols, row = frame_contact_list.grid_size()
    ttk.Label(frame_contact_list, text=contact["name"]).grid(column=1, row=row, padx="12")
    ttk.Label(frame_contact_list, text=contact["phone"]).grid(column=2, row=row, padx="10")
    ttk.Label(frame_contact_list, text=contact["email"]).grid(column=3, row=row, padx="10")


def remove_contact(contacts):
    sleep(1)
    list_name_contacts = []
    digit_list = []
    name_digit = 0
    for contact in contacts:
        name_contact = contact['name']
        list_name_contacts.append(name_contact)

    print("\n\nEliminar contacto\n")
    sleep(1)
    print("\n¿Qué contacto quieres eliminar?\n")
    sleep(2)

    for contact_name in list_name_contacts:
        print("{}-{}".format(name_digit, contact_name))
        digit_list.append(name_digit)
        name_digit += 1
    digit_contact_eliminate = int(input("Diga el número del contacto que desea eliminar "))
    for digit in digit_list:
        if digit_contact_eliminate == digit:
            contacts.pop(digit_contact_eliminate)
    sleep(2)


def load_contacts():
    try:
        return pickle.load(open(SAVE_FILE_NAME, "rb"))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return []


def take_contact_from_contacts(contacts):
    contacts_to_show = []
    for i in contacts:
        name = i.get("name")
        phone = i.get("phone")
        email = i.get("email")
        contact = {
            "name": name,
            "phone": phone,
            "email": email
        }
        contacts_to_show.append(contact)
    return contacts_to_show


def show_saved_contacts(frame_contact_list, contacts):
    contacts = take_contact_from_contacts(contacts)
    for contact in contacts:
        cols, row = frame_contact_list.grid_size()
        ttk.Label(frame_contact_list, text=contact["name"]).grid(column=1, row=row, padx="12")
        ttk.Label(frame_contact_list, text=contact["phone"]).grid(column=2, row=row, padx="10")
        ttk.Label(frame_contact_list, text=contact["email"]).grid(column=3, row=row, padx="10")


def save_contacts(contacts):
    with open(SAVE_FILE_NAME, "wb") as save_file:
        pickle.dump(contacts, save_file)
    print("Datos guardados correctamente.")


def main():
    contacts = load_contacts()

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Agenda de contactos")
    frame_add_contact = ttk.Frame(root, padding="30 12 30 12")
    frame_add_contact.grid()

    frame_contact_list = ttk.Frame(root, padding="30 12 30 12")
    frame_contact_list.grid()

    name = StringVar()
    phone = StringVar()
    email = StringVar()

    ttk.Label(frame_add_contact, text="Nombre").grid(column=1, row=1)
    ttk.Label(frame_add_contact, text="Teléfono").grid(column=2, row=1)
    ttk.Label(frame_add_contact, text="E-mail").grid(column=3, row=1)

    ttk.Entry(frame_add_contact, width=10, textvariable=name).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W, padx="10")
    ttk.Entry(frame_add_contact, width=10, textvariable=phone).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=W, padx="10")
    ttk.Entry(frame_add_contact, width=10, textvariable=email).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W, padx="10")

    ttk.Label(frame_contact_list, text="Nombre").grid(column=1, row=1, padx="12")
    ttk.Label(frame_contact_list, text="Teléfono").grid(column=2, row=1, padx="10")
    ttk.Label(frame_contact_list, text="E-mail").grid(column=3, row=1, padx="10")

    ttk.Button(frame_add_contact,
               text="Añadir",
               command=lambda: add_contact_tk(contacts, name.get(), phone.get(), email.get(), frame_contact_list)
               ).grid(column=3, row=3, pady="8")

    ttk.Button(frame_add_contact, text="Cargar contactos", command=show_saved_contacts(frame_contact_list, contacts
                                                                                       )).grid(column=1, row=3,
                                                                                               pady="8")

    ttk.Button(frame_add_contact, text="Guardar contactos", command=save_contacts(contacts)).grid(column=1, row=4,
                                                                                                  pady="8")

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Una cosa, la función `remove_contact` está ahí porque el programa anteriormente era una agenda basada en texto, tengo planeado cambiarla para poder usarla en UI (pero aún no sé como xd).

Comment: No estoy seguro pero puede que sea por falta de un puntero, estoy acostumbrado a guardar estas cosas en variables del tipo `self.contacts` para uso posterior. Es posible que el collector de basura te esté borrando los datos de esa variable. Y aunque ese no sea el problema, deberías pensar en mejorar el código con classes.

Comment: Disculpa apenas estoy aprendiendo y la verdad varias palabras no las entiendo jajaja. ¿Qué es el ```self.```? y eso del colector de basura? Con eso de las clases te refieres a los objetos no? es que aún no he lla¡egado a esa parte del curso.

Comment: Si, las clases pueden ser objetos, instanciarlos te asegura que hay una referencia activa. Mantener una referencia activa a un objeto evita que el recolector de basura elimine esos datos: https://riptutorial.com/es/python/topic/2532/recoleccion-de-basura
 Respecto a `self` es una manera de acceder a datos de una clase.